# python Qlabel text is not updated as I expect

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

I have a question about Qlabel.
Following is the example of code. While opertaiong the program, I want to show message that the system is operating.
But somehow Qlabel message was not updated as I expected.
“self.text_label.setText('reading file ......')  “ area of following code. (this is not shown as expected)

And at the end Qlabel text was updated.
“self.text_label.setText('opertaion finish') “   area
(this is shown as expected)

If there is any mistake or missing information, please advise.

```
import  os , sys, time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout,
     QApplication,QPushButton,QWidget,QRadioButton,QLabel,QTextEdit)  
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #overall layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
                
        # Pushbutton for excution         
        bt_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        bt_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,20)
        start_bt = QPushButton("start")
        start_bt.setStyleSheet("background-color:lightblue")        
        bt_layout.addWidget(start_bt)
        start_bt.clicked.connect(self.start)
        layout.addLayout(bt_layout)
 
        text_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.text_label = QLabel()
        self.text_label.setText('before operation') 
        text_layout.addWidget(self.text_label)                    
        layout.addLayout(text_layout)

        #overall layout        
        self.container = QWidget()
        self.container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)               
        self.setGeometry(500, 100, 330, 200)
        self.show()
    
    def start(self):
        self.text_label.setText('reading file ......')   
        time.sleep(5)
            
        self.text_label.setText('opertaion finish')   
        self.text_label.setStyleSheet("background-color:#00FF00 ")        
        
# call the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Whatever you're doing instead of `time.sleep()`, it's blocking the event loop, preventing it to properly redraw the label. You could add a `QApplication.processEvent()` there, but there's no guarantee it will suffice. If you need to do some time consuming file read/processing, you probably need a separate worker QThread with appropriate signals (note that UI elements are **NOT** thread-safe, and you shall never access them from external threads). Also, it's spelled "operation" and "operating", not "opertaion" or "opertaiong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to for the label to update in real time then you can use `QTimer` and it's `singleShot` class method to trigger the update once the pre-set amount of time has completely elapsed.

For example you can call the `QTimer.singleShot` in your `start` method just after setting the label text to "reading file.......", and set the callback to another method that performs the rest of the label updates after 5 seconds.

```
...
from PyQt5 import QtCore
...

...
...

    def start(self):
        self.text_label.setText('reading file ......')
        QtCore.QTimer().singleShot(5000, self.updateLabel)

    def updateLabel(self):
        self.text_label.setText('operation finish')
        self.text_label.setStyleSheet("background-color:#00FF00 ")
```

This won't be of much help though if you actually are going to be opening a file that takes 5 seconds to read. If this is the case then you will likely want to perform that operation in a different thread and then pass the read data from the thread once it has finished reading it by connecting to a signal that sends the read data when it emits.

For example:

```
class ReadThread(QThread):
    fileRead = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = filename

    def run(self):
        with open(self.filename) as file:
            data = file.read()
        self.fileRead.emit(data)
        

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        ...

    def updateLabel(self, data):
        ... do something with data
        self.text_label.setText('operation finish')
        self.text_label.setStyleSheet("background-color:#00FF00 ")


    def start(self):
        self.text_label.setText('reading file ......')
        self.thread = ReadThread(filename)
        self.thread.fileRead.connect(self.updateLabel)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater())
        self.thread.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
The problem was solved by QTimer method.

Comment: @Taniguchi  Your welcome, feel free to mark your question as solved if your issue has been resolved.